# Edge that lies between multiple vertices of a given tree

Tags: algorithm

I have a tree with N vertices v1, v2, v3.... vN . Tree is hanged on vertex v1. Now I have chosen some random paths in the tree. How to know if there is an edge in the tree that lies on all these chosen paths?

EDIT- All the paths are bi-directional.

Comment: Do all your paths start at v1?

Comment: suppose there is a path v2->v3->v4->v5 and another path is v6->v3->v4->v7 . These paths dont start with same edge but the they do share a common path v3->v4 . Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: No it is not guaranteed that all paths start at v1.

Comment: take your shortest path (because it has the fewest edges) and check whether any of its edges is on all other paths; start the iterations with short paths. not terribly efficient though

Comment: alternatively, store in each edge how many paths you chose it for; compare with the number of paths you chose.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by G. Bach, you iterate through each path, and in the process you record, for each edge, the number of times it is included in a path. At the end, you can iterate over the edge set and the edge (or edges) that has the same count as the number of paths will be an edge that lies on all the chosen paths.

As there are exactly `n-1` edges in a tree, this algorithm is `O(n)`, and I guess is the most efficient already.